# Handling XML response with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, fetch

I'm making a request to an API for some information. I need to send some information in order to get the required information back. The response is in XML format. When I make the request I get the following error

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

If a GET request can't have a body how do I send the required information? Basically how do I get this to work?

Here is my code.

```
getResponse = () => {

  const url = 'http://api.pixelz.com/REST.svc/Templates/';

  // The data we are going to send in our request

  let data = JSON.stringify({
    "contactEmail": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "contactAPIkey": "MY-API-KEY"
  })

  // The parameters we are gonna pass to the fetch function

  let fetchData = { 
    method: 'GET', 
    body: data,
    headers: new Headers()
  }

  fetch(url, fetchData)
    .then(function(response) {
      // Handle response you get from the server
      response.text()
      .then(data => console.log(data))
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed GET requests can't have a body, meaning you don't send data while you are getting.  There can be two things going on here.

1. That specific endpoint is supposed to use another method like `POST`
2. The data you want to send actually needs to be passed as querystring parameter `http://api.pixelz.com/REST.svc/Templates/?contactAPIkey=....&contactEmail=...`

Comment: The http protocol has the concept of verbs, like GET and POST.  Each verb has a different reason or meaning.  GET is for getting static files, POST is to provide information to the server (generally to create a resource).

For that reason, the creators of http decided that sending data on a GET doesn't make logical sense.